# How to set different localization file for different users?

Tags: theme-development, localization

I am trying to load localization file depends on users settings. Is this way is correct or there are better ways to implement locale changing depends on user settings?

```
    <?php
           add_filter( 'locale', 'theme_localized' );

            function theme_localized( )
            {
                if(is_user_logged_in()) {
                    $locale = get_user_locale();
                     return $locale;
                }

            }
?>
```

This code is working but I am not sure that this is the conventional way of translating website.

Answer (score 0):

By default WordPress only loads translations according to the user's language when they're viewing **admin** pages.

You can see that in the code for the [load_theme_textdomain](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_theme_textdomain/) function:

```
$locale = apply_filters( 'theme_locale',
    is_admin() ? get_user_locale() : get_locale(),
//  ^^^^^^^^
$domain );
```

So your code is fine if you want to override that behaviour for the front end of your site.

Is it conventional? Well, this is what filters are for. However, I'd say this isn't normally done unless the language of the actual **content** is also changing.